# Looking for a proper math notation to deal with intervals

Tags: notation, convention, interval-arithmetic

Say we have two sets like this:

$A = \{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9,a_{10}\}$ and $B = \{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5,b_6,b_7,b_8,b_9,b_{10}\}$

I want to be able to build something like this: $[(a_{1},b_{1}),(a_{3},b_{3}),(a_{6},b_{6})),(a_{7},b_{7})]$.

So I came up with this notation:

*Let A be a m-sized set like this $\{a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{m}\}$.*

*Then I build an array of pairs like this $[(a_{j},b_{j}),\cdots,(a_{k},b_{k})]$ where $a_{i}\in A'\subseteq A$ and $b_{i}\in B'\subseteq B$, with $1 \leq j \leq i \leq k \leq m $.*

The problem with the notation above is that it might appear that I must pick every $a_{i} \in A$ with $i$ between $j$ and $k$.
In fact, I want the notation to capture the idea that I can build the array of pairs by picking any element $a_{i} \in A$ with $i$ between $j$ and $k$ and being able to skip some elements of $A$.

Comment: I would suggest a notation like: $[(a_{n_{1}},b_{n_{1}}),...,(a_{n_{k}},b_{n_{k}})]$ with $1\leq n_{1}\leq...\leq n_{k}\leq m$.

Comment: Sorry? What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally hit enter to early...

Comment: Thanks, @FlorisClaassens. Now, if I want to say that some property holds true for all the elements $\{a_{n_1},\cdots,a_{n_k}\}$ with $1\leq n_{1}\leq \cdots \leq n_{k} \leq m$, could I just say: *property $x$ holds true for all $a_{i}$* with $n_{1} \leq i \leq n_{k}$ ?

Comment: No, as that would again imply the property holds for all $n_{1}\leq i\leq n_{k}$ while I think you want the property to hold for all $a_{n_{i}}$ for  $1\leq i\leq k$.

Comment: Thanks again, @FlorisClaassens. :)

Comment: @FlorisClaassens could you please post what you have written as a proper answer so I can mark your answer as the solution to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following notation: $[(a_{n_{1}},b_{n_{1}}),...,(a_{n_{k}},b_{n_{k}})]$ with $1\leq n_{1}\leq...\leq n_{k}\leq m$.